# Sql Server how to union 2 WITH datasets when I cannot join them

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, union

I want to union 2 `WITH` data sets , but it is a bit complicated, because first `WITH` dataset I collect from one table and other `WITH` statement from another table, but columns which I select are the same from different tables.

This is how my to `WITH` selects looks like:

```
;WITH A AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT PROJECTID, 
            SUBSTRING(redirect, CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6), CHARINDEX('.aspx', redirect) - CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6)) Link,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%s-1.mytest.com%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS tinyint) PROJECTS_DOMAINID,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%/test_p%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS BIT) test_project
    FROM LOG_REDIRECT WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE (is_valid = 1) AND (INSERT_DATE > @date_from) -- AND (PROJECTID = 120515) 
    )

    INSERT INTO #temp_Tbl ( PROJECTID, Link, PROJECTS_DOMAINID, test_project)
```

Ant another `WITH` statement with same INSERT

```
    ;WITH B as 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            PROJECTID
            , SUBSTRING(ds.link, 0, CHARINDEX('?__', ds.link)) AS link 
            FROM dbo.LINKS_PROJECTS as PROJECTS_DOMAINID
        WHERE ds.link > '' AND ds.link LIKE '%mytest.com%' AND (ds.INSERT_DATE > @date_from  OR ds.UPDATE_DATE > @date_from)
        )
INSERT INTO #temp_Tbl ( PROJECTID, Link, PROJECTS_DOMAINID, test_project)
```

How can I `union` these 2 `WITH` datasets? Basically I want to union, because I think I can use one `INSERT` instead of two `INSERTS` to same temporary table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH A AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT PROJECTID, 
            SUBSTRING(redirect, CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6), CHARINDEX('.aspx', redirect) - CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6)) Link,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%s-1.mytest.com%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS tinyint) PROJECTS_DOMAINID,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%/test_p%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS BIT) test_project
    FROM LOG_REDIRECT WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE (is_valid = 1) AND (INSERT_DATE > @date_from) -- AND (PROJECTID = 120515) 
    ),  B as 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            PROJECTID
            , SUBSTRING(ds.link, 0, CHARINDEX('?__', ds.link)) AS link 
            FROM dbo.LINKS_PROJECTS as PROJECTS_DOMAINID
        WHERE ds.link > '' AND ds.link LIKE '%mytest.com%' AND (ds.INSERT_DATE > @date_from  OR ds.UPDATE_DATE > @date_from)
        )
INSERT INTO #temp_Tbl ( PROJECTID, Link, PROJECTS_DOMAINID, test_project)
SELECT * FROM A
UNION
SELECT * FROM B
```

Answer (score 0):

We can have only one with clause for this.

```
INSERT INTO #temp_Tbl ( PROJECTID, Link, PROJECTS_DOMAINID, test_project)
WITH A AS
    (
    SELECT PROJECTID, 
            SUBSTRING(redirect, CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6), CHARINDEX('.aspx', redirect) - CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6)) Link,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%s-1.mytest.com%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS tinyint) PROJECTS_DOMAINID,
            CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%/test_p%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS BIT) test_project
    FROM LOG_REDIRECT WITH(NOLOCK) 
    WHERE (is_valid = 1) AND (INSERT_DATE > @date_from) -- AND (PROJECTID = 120515) 
  UNION
        SELECT 
            PROJECTID
            , SUBSTRING(ds.link, 0, CHARINDEX('?__', ds.link)) AS link 
            FROM dbo.LINKS_PROJECTS as PROJECTS_DOMAINID
        WHERE ds.link > '' AND ds.link LIKE '%mytest.com%' AND (ds.INSERT_DATE > @date_from  OR ds.UPDATE_DATE > @date_from)
    )
select PROJECTID, Link, PROJECTS_DOMAINID, test_project from A;
```

No need to have two distincts as UNION removes the duplicates and then inserts the data into the temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this a bit different way:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_Tbl') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_TblA

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_Tbl') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_TblB

SELECT DISTINCT PROJECTID, 
        SUBSTRING(redirect, CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6), CHARINDEX('.aspx', redirect) - CHARINDEX('p', redirect, 6)) Link,
        CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%s-1.mytest.com%' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS tinyint) PROJECTS_DOMAINID,
        CAST(CASE WHEN redirect LIKE '%/test_p%' THEN 1 else 0 END AS BIT) test_project
INTO  #temp_Tbl  
FROM LOG_REDIRECT WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE (is_valid = 1) AND (INSERT_DATE > @date_from) -- AND (PROJECTID = 120515) 

SELECT DISTINCT  PROJECTID,
       SUBSTRING(ds.link, 0, CHARINDEX('?__', ds.link)) AS link
       NULL AS PROJECTS_DOMAINID, -- Or put your logic 
       NULL AS test_project, -- or put your logic to get value 
INTO   #temp_TblB
FROM   dbo.LINKS_PROJECTS  AS PROJECTS_DOMAINID
WHERE  ds.link > ''
       AND ds.link LIKE '%mytest.com%'
       AND (ds.INSERT_DATE > @date_from OR ds.UPDATE_DATE > @date_from)


-- Final Result 

SELECT * FROM #temp_TblA
UNION 
SELECT * FROM #temp_TblB

-- Cleanup 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_Tbl') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_TblA

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_Tbl') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp_TblB
```